# How to use an infinite animation effect?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in java, android studio.

I have a dynamically populated ListView that contains an image.

```
public class adapterListProd extends BaseAdapter {
                private final List<Produto> Produtos;
                private final Activity act;
                private final Context ctx;
                private AlertDialog alerta;

                public Double precoAtual;

                public adapterListProd(List<Produto> Produtos, Activity act, Context ctx) {
                    this.Produtos = Produtos;
                    this.act = act;
                    this.ctx = ctx;
                }

                /*public adapterListProd(List<String> nomeProdutos,List<Integer> imageProdutos, Activity act) {
                    this.Produtos = Produtos;
                    this.act = act;
                }*/

                @Override
                public int getCount() {

                    return Produtos.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {

                    return Produtos.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {

                    return Produtos.get(position).getId();
                }


                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    final DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#.00");


                    final Produto Prod = Produtos.get(position);
                    View view;
                    TextView nome;
                    ImageView imagem;
                    imagem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                    imagem.setImageDrawable(Prod.getImagem());
    }
  }
```

I wish these images would move endlessly ...alternating...looping

```
Animation left_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
Animation right_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, android.R.anim.slide_in_right);
```

I believe I can't use one "while" so the listView construct would get stuck in the first item.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

no need to use callback method in order to be able start animation again so below code piece is enough to do this

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

[official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#INFINITE)

Comment: yes but if we have a view in which we want to apply two different animations ( left and right )infinitely how would you achieve that using animation

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different animations one for slide right and other for slide left..
i would suggest you to use android **AnimatorSet** to avoid looping like this:-

```
 final AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator animateLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imagem, "translationX", 0, 10f);
    ObjectAnimator animateRight = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imagem, "translationX", 10f, 0);
    animatorSet.playSequentially(animateLeft, animateRight);

    animatorSet.start();
    animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    });
```

So here whenever your animation finishes you can start the animation again.
10 is how much distance you want to translate your imageview in x-axis respect to each **ObjectAnimator**

i hope this would help you